# React render state not the real state

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I try to set my arr's loading to false one by one after one second.But the render function in the html seem to be not the same with state in the react dev tools.
Here is the code and snipaste.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const App = (p: any) => {
  console.log('render!!');
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([{}, {}, {}, {}]);

  useEffect(() => {
    changeArr();
  }, []);

  const changeArr = async () => {
    const localArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      const p = new Promise(res => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          res('');
        }, 1000);
      });
      const res = await p;
      localArr[i].loading = false;
      setArr(localArr);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(arr)}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[snipaste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD0is.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `then` to get the result of the promise

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([{}, {}, {}, {}]);

  useEffect(() => {
    changeArray();
  }, []);
  function myPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("");
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  async function changeArray() {
    JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      await myPromise().then(() => {
        const newArray = [...array];
        newArray[i].loading = false;
        setArray(newArray);
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(array)}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: It looks like you didn't get what I say.You can have a look at my snipaste picture.The code you give works is because you used `const newArray = [...newArray]`.You create a shallow copy of the array state.But what I don't know is why the state in dev tools is incompatible with what I return in the component, which is shown in my snipaste.